# .rounded-lg is not working for table in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Currently, I am using Tailwind CSS version 3.3.3.

I am not getting the rounded corners for the table. I have tried to add a wrapper container with the classes `"overflow-hidden rounded-lg"`. The radius issue was solved, but the corner borders of each side disappeared. How can I solve this issue?

My code is:

```
<table class="w-50 m-auto font-inter text-left border-collapse rounded-lg">
    <thead>
         <tr class="bg-[#f2f4f7]">
              <th class="p-3 text-gray-500 text-xs font-semibold leading-none border border-gray-200"><span class="inline-flex gap-1">Plan</span></th>
              <th class="p-3 text-gray-500 text-xs font-semibold leading-none border border-gray-200"><span class="inline-flex gap-1">No. of Subscription</span></th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <body>
          <tr>
               <td class="border border-gray-200 p-3">Silver plan USD Monthly</td>
               <td class="border border-gray-200 p-3">2</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's applied but `thead` makes the top radius not show correctly. if you use `overflow:hidden` it will work.

Comment: For my code, the overflow:hidden needed to be on the table itself.